# Unity 2D: Rigidbody2D 'addforce' works vertically but not horizontally?

Tags: unity-game-engine

EDIT! So I loaded up a FRESH PROJECT, created a circle and added my script to it. When I hit start the circle launches off at a 45 degree angle, it works perfectly fine. I also tried adding a horizontal addforce on another object in my original project and it resulted in a jittery teleport to the right.

Something is broken inside my project related to horizontal force... What could it be?!

This has driven me and a bud mad for 24 hours now and I've searched high and low but have not found any similar problems or applicable solutions.

I'm developing a mario-style side scroller game and the concept is simple: Hit the box, a coin pops out with vertical and horizontal force. This is the ONLY code so far in the script attached to the coin.

```
void Start()
{
 forceUp = new Vector2(0, upForce);
 forceSide = new Vector2(sideForce, 0);
 GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(forceUp, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
 GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(forceSide, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

This is the code that instantiates the coin in the box script:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
 
{
 RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, 1.0f, layerMask);
 
 if (!isOpen && hit.collider != null)
 {
     isOpened();
     Instantiate(openPrize, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y+1.0f, transform.position.z), transform.rotation);
 }
}
```

problem is: The coin will pop "up" a distance directly related to the value I plug into the "up force" variable.

The coin will not move horizontally at all. If I jack the horizontal variable up to some stupid number like 5000, it will teleport a short distance to the side.

the animator of the prefab has "Apply root motion" enabled.

Comment: I just tested out your code and I'm getting both horizontal and vertical movement. I put the coin code on a sprite with a `Rigidbody2D` component which I turned into a prefab. Then I put the `Instantiate` line from the `OnCollisionEnter2D` in a separate script in the start function with openPrize set to the prefab and when I press play I get a sprite appear and bounce up and to the right.  Could the teleporting a short distance to the side be down to the `+1.0f` that's getting added to the y position in the Instantiate line? (I'm using Unity 2019.4.10f1).

Comment: Any chance you've accidentally checked one of the constrain checkboxes in the `Rigidbody2D` component and frozen the y axis?

Comment: I have not checked any constraint boxes aside from freezing Z rotation.  I'm using the newest version, 2020 i think, so perhaps they've broken something?  

The +1.0f just makes it spawn above the box it's "popping out" of.  For shits and giggles I deleted it and it made no difference.  Still has no horizontal movement.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a new project and testing out whether it works on its own without any other scripts or game objects or anything else that could be interfering?

Comment: I just did what you suggested... and the script works perfectly.  

Now I am extremely confused...  Any suggestions?

Comment: So for shits and giggles I added characterBody.AddForce(new Vector2(800, 0)); to my "jump" code (it adds 800 force upward when jumping, so should be 45 degree angle) which is a completely different script and it does the SAME THING.  Just a little jittery teleport right, no adding of force.

Comment: Sounds like some kind of universal setting. Try checking in the Player Settings for something off in the Physics or Physics2D section (It's in file > build settings and there's a button in the bottom left called Player Settings) I can't think what it could be in there that could be causing it though.

Comment: I figured it out...  There is a setting in the animator of the prefab im using called "Apply root motion".  I have never used it, dunno what it does but it was checked by default in the asset i imported and that was somehow stopping the movement.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out... There is a setting in the animator of the prefab im using called "Apply root motion". I have never used it, dunno what it does but it was checked by default in the asset i imported and that was somehow stopping the movement. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your forcemode is probably not right.

[Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode2D.Impulse.html):

> Apply the impulse force instantly. [...] This mode is useful for
> applying forces that happen instantly, such as forces from explosions
> or collisions.

Probabaly `ForceMode2D.Force` is better.

> This mode is useful for setting up realistic physics where it takes
> more force to move heavier objects.

But maybe it's because you apply to forces at once. Try this:

```
// Force up
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
// Force side
```

Comment: I've tried adding them together in the same vector: new Vector2(sideForce, upforce); that still resulted in no horizontal movement.

I'm not familiar with the 'await' and when I tried to add your snippet it said Task.Delay doesnt exist.